# Deleting registry keys and folders with CMD using messages and pauses

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-registry, teamviewer

I make a script to delete some keys from registry and some files and folders from computer. I want to know why i'm getting errors even if all keys and folders exists.

Errors is that it says that keys don't exists, same as folders don't exists but all exists and i double checked even after restart of computer.

Was Run as admin, system is Windows 10, x64

```
@echo off
echo Deleting registry keys
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TeamViewer" /f
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer" /f
reg delete "HKCR\TeamViewerConfiguration" /f
reg delete "HKCR\TeamViewerSession" /f
timeout /t 5

echo Deleting Team View from program files
del /S /Q C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer
rmdir /S /Q C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer
timeout /t 3

echo Deleting Team view
del /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer
timeout /t 3

echo Deleting Team View
del /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TeamViewer
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TeamViewer
timeout /t 3
exit
```

Comment: We can't help unless you specify which errors

Comment: Errors is that keys don't exists, same as folders but all exists i double checked even after restart of computer.

Comment: Update your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Error is that it says that keys don't exist

You don't need `"`s around the `keyname`:

```
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TeamViewer /f
reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer /f
reg delete HKCR\TeamViewerConfiguration /f
reg delete HKCR\TeamViewerSession /f
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [Reg delete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
echo Deleting registry keys
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TeamViewer" /f
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer" /f
reg delete "HKCR\TeamViewerConfiguration" /f
reg delete "HKCR\TeamViewerSession" /f
timeout /t 5

echo Deleting Team View from program files
del /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer"
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer"
timeout /t 3

echo Deleting Team view
del /S /Q "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer"
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer"
timeout /t 3

echo Deleting Team View
del /S /Q "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TeamViewer"
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TeamViewer"
timeout /t 3
exit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).